# Selenium program_Valid URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am just starting with selenium.

I made simple java program that should open a url and print the text.

Here it is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Webdriver_class
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("hello this is ajay");
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

After running the code it shows URL is not valid.
Even I've added all the libraries. Could you please help out for resolving the same.

Comment: Which version of Firefox and Selenium you are using? Because, this code works for me with Selenium  v2.53.1 and FF v47.0.1.

Comment: I'm using - FF - V47.0.1 and Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Comment: Which version of Selenium you are using?

Comment: What do you mean URL is not valid?? What is the exact exception???